# EagerLoadingError [SequelizeEagerLoadingError]: Cartproduct is not associated to Cart

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

I look some other related posts in the forum an no one of them is helping me.

As the title says I have the classic problem model associations with Sequelize but I dont know why because code and associations seems good.

My models;

CART MODEL

```
"use strict";
const { Model } = require("sequelize");
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Cart extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      Cart.belongsTo(models.User, {
        foreignKey: "userid"
      });
      Cart.belongsToMany(models.Productstore, {
        through: "Cartproduct",
        foreignKey: "CartId"
      });
    }
  }
  Cart.init(
    {
      userid: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
          model: "User",
          key: "id"
        }
      },
      quantity: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER
      }
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: "Cart"
    }
  );
  return Cart;
};
```

CART MIGRATION

```
'use strict';
/** @type {import('sequelize-cli').Migration} */
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('Carts', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      quantity: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      userid: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: "Users",
          key: "id",
        },
        onDelete: "cascade",
        onUpdate: "cascade",
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('Carts');
  }
};
```

CARTPRODUCT MODEL

```
"use strict";
const { Model } = require("sequelize");
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Cartproduct extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      Cartproduct.belongsTo(models.Cart, {
        foreignKey: "CartId",
      });
      Cartproduct.belongsTo(models.Productstore, {
        foreignKey: "productstoreid",
      });
    }
  }
  Cartproduct.init(
    {
      CartId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
          model: "Cart",
          key: "id",
        },
      },
      productstoreid: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
          model: "Productstore",
          key: "id",
        },
      },

      quantity: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: "Cartproduct",
    }
  );
  return Cartproduct;
};
```

CARTPRODUCT MIGRATION

```
'use strict';
/** @type {import('sequelize-cli').Migration} */
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('Cartproducts', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      CartId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: "Carts",
          key: "id",
        },
        onDelete: "cascade",
        onUpdate: "cascade",
      },
      productstoreid: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: "Productstores",
          key: "id",
        },
        onDelete: "cascade",
        onUpdate: "cascade",
      },
     
      quantity: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
     
   
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('Cartproducts');
  }
};
```

**makeOrder controller function;**

```
const models = require("../models/index");
const { Cart, Cartproduct, Productstore, Orders, Orderproduct } = models;

const makeOrder = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const userid = req.auth.user.id;

    const cart = await Cart.findOne({
        CartId:Cart.id,
      where: {
        userid,
      },
      
      include: [Cartproduct],
    });

    if (!cart) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: "Cart not found" });
    }

    const order = await Orders.create({
      userid,
      ships: req.body.ships,
    });

    const productsInCart = cart.Cartproducts;
    for (const productInCart of productsInCart) {
      await Orderproduct.create({
        orderid: order.id,
        productstoreid: productInCart.productstoreid,
        quantity: productInCart.quantity,
      });
      const productstore = await Productstore.findByPk(
        productInCart.productstoreid
      );
      if (productstore) {
        productstore.stock -= productInCart.quantity;
        await productstore.save();
      }
    }
    res
      .status(201)
      .json({
        message:
          "Your order has been send to our headquarters, will be shipped in the next 24h. Thank your very much.",
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Cant make the order, please try again" });
  }
};

module.exports = {
  makeOrder,
};
```

In mySQL I have the table Cartproducts with all the correct columns and has CartId with value 1 because previously I added products with another function controller named addProductsToCart.

If anyone is asking why CartId is typed with capital letters on the "C" and the "I" is because Sequelize rename it with no reason during the migrations with all the asociations only with this table/column so I change my cartid for CartId to solve the duplicated twice error.

I think the problem its only located on the associations and should be something done by Sequelize behind the curtain.

Comment: Please show the content of a module where you register models and their associations